# Make html responsive

Tags: html

I'am pretty new to Html. I have a web page I need to make responsive to use on tablets and mobiles. What do I need to do to make this happen.

styles:

```
    #header {
        font-size:30px; 
        color:white;
        text-align:center; 
        padding-top:10px; 
        padding-bottom:10px;
    }


</style>
```

html:

```
<div style="background-image:url(); height:350px; width:900px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
    <div id="header">text</div>
    <div id="para">text</br>text</div>
    <div id="splash_img"><img src=""/></div>

    <div id="game_img"><img src="" /> 

        <div id="video_play"><img src=""/></div>
       </div>
```

form:

```
        <div id="form_container"><div id="form"><form>
        <div class="form_label">Name:</div> <div class="form_input"><input type="text" name="firstname" style="width:200px; display:inline-block"></div>
        <div class="form_label">Surname:</div> <div class="form_input"><input type="text" name="lastname"style="width:200px; display:inline-block"></div>
        <div class="form_label">Email: </div><div class="form_input"><input type="text" name="email"style="width:200px; display:inline-block"></div>
        <div style="padding-left:40px; padding-top:10px"><input type="submit" value="text"></div>
        </form></div></div>

</div>
```

Comment: This markup is something out of a nightmare! The first thing you should do before wanting to make this responsive is remove all your `style` attributes and instead use an external stylesheet.

Comment: Separate your CSS from your HTML first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few libraries that you could find helpful. And it is a nightmare code. You really need to remove those `css` from HTML and import them in `css` file.

```
http://angrycreative.se/modern-css-frameworks-for-desktop-tablet-mobile/

http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/responsive-layouts-using-css-media-queries/
```